# Using CASE Statement in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a Stored Procedure that calls other Stored Procedures depending on the Input parameters specified.

This is how it looks:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_SPCaller
@Input_Param1 NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
@Input_Param2 NVARCHAR(100) = NULL

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON    

IF ((@Input_Param1 IS NOT NULL) AND (@Input_Param2 IS NOT NULL))
   BEGIN
       EXEC dbo.usp_SPWithParam1And2
   END 

IF ((@Input_Param1 IS NOT NULL) AND (@Input_Param2 IS NULL))
   BEGIN
       EXEC dbo.usp_SPWithParam1Only
   END

IF ((@Input_Param1 IS NULL) AND (@Input_Param2 IS NOT NULL))
   BEGIN
       EXEC dbo.usp_SPWithParam2Only
   END

IF ((@Input_Param1 IS NULL) AND (@Input_Param2 IS NULL))
   BEGIN
       EXEC dbo.usp_SPWithoutParam1And2
   END
```

After presenting this to our lead, he advised me to use CASE STATEMENTS instead because using IF STATEMENTS is a bad idea.

I tried searching everywhere on how to use CASE STATEMENTS in the same format as I have above but to no avail. All I find is using CASE STATEMENTS together with UPDATE.

### My question

How do I use CASE STATEMENTS in SQL SERVER in a way that it looks like the above?

Comment: The CASE statement is used to select/return the data not for executing stored procedures. However, you'd better use IF ELSE IF instead of actual code.

Comment: The best guess was deleted just now by the author: nobody asked OP to split code into several SPs and to invent `spCaller` (which smells very bad and reminds me a beginner style) and everything can and should be accomplished within one SP with CASE statement applied to whatever it is supposed to be applied to (predicates in `WHERE` clause I guess). Therefore, this code is supposed to be vanished, the new SP with probably single T-SQL statement is required.

Comment: I used to do all the logic for all SPs in a single SP but when I presented it, I was told that each SP should follow the Single Responsibility principle, and so I split them all accordingly since they each do different things. Does this mean that when creating stored procedures, you should merge all of them into one and not do it like what you would do in coding programming languages?

Comment: "Single responsibility" principle does not say `wake up and create spCaller proc now!` How are we supposed to know what is going on within those sps or where this outer proc is being invoked from? Here you go with another guess:the outer proc must not exist, caller must invoke specific proc directly. Your question is so vague and abstract that anyone can share a dozen of possible scenarios how to redesign it. Talk to you lead. Itching for `he is wrong!` answers is a no go.

Comment: I am not asking for "he is wrong" answers. All I'm saying is, I separated each Stored Procedure because they do different things. And as per my understanding of Single Responsibility that one class must do one thing and one thing alone. And by putting them all into one SP like what I did before, I violated that principle. I came here for answers to my question and nothing more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lead is wrong. In fact there is no such thing as a `case statement` in SQL Server, it is a `case expression`.

> "The CASE expression cannot be used to control the flow of execution of Transact-SQL statements, statement blocks, user-defined functions, and stored procedures."

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 5):

Try this code..
Here I am storing the procedure name (that is to be executed) in a variable named `@sql` and at the end executing this variable using `sp_executesql`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_SPCaller 
@Input_Param1 NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
@Input_Param2 NVARCHAR(100) = NULL

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

set @sql = case 
   when ((@Input_Param1 IS NOT NULL) AND (@Input_Param2 IS NOT NULL))
   then 'dbo.usp_SPWithParam1And2'

   when ((@Input_Param1 IS NOT NULL) AND (@Input_Param2 IS NULL))
   then 'dbo.usp_SPWithParam1Only'

   when((@Input_Param1 IS NULL) AND (@Input_Param2 IS NOT NULL))
   then 'dbo.usp_SPWithParam2Only'

   when ((@Input_Param1 IS NULL) AND (@Input_Param2 IS NULL))
   then 'dbo.usp_SPWithoutParam1And2'

   END

   print @sql
   EXEC sp_executesql @sql
end
```

Comment: `sp_executesql` is not required here. SP call by name is done via `exec @spname`

Comment: This is funny. The answer `he is wron!!` was double upvoted and accepted, and the answer giving literally (almost) what was asked - is downvoted.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid your team leader is wrong.

To quote the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms181765%28v%3dsql.105%29):

> The CASE expression cannot be used to control the flow of execution of
>   Transact-SQL statements, statement blocks, user-defined functions, and
>   stored procedures. For a list of control-of-flow methods, see
>   Control-of-Flow Language (Transact-SQL).

The Transact-SQL control-of-flow language keywords are (no `CASE` there):

```
 - BEGIN...END
 - RETURN
 - BREAK
 - TRY...CATCH
 - CONTINUE
 - WAITFOR
 - GOTO label
 - WHILE
 - IF...ELSE
```

On the other hand your query **could be improved** (no need to check the other `IF(s)` if the condition is satisfied:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_SPCaller
@Input_Param1 NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
@Input_Param2 NVARCHAR(100) = NULL

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON    

IF ((@Input_Param1 IS NOT NULL) AND (@Input_Param2 IS NOT NULL))
   BEGIN
       EXEC dbo.usp_SPWithParam1And2
   END 
ELSE IF ((@Input_Param1 IS NOT NULL) AND (@Input_Param2 IS NULL))
   BEGIN
       EXEC dbo.usp_SPWithParam1Only
   END
ELSE IF ((@Input_Param1 IS NULL) AND (@Input_Param2 IS NOT NULL))
   BEGIN
       EXEC dbo.usp_SPWithParam2Only
   END  
ELSE IF ((@Input_Param1 IS NULL) AND (@Input_Param2 IS NULL))
   BEGIN
       EXEC dbo.usp_SPWithoutParam1And2
   END
```

### **EDIT** - due to dynamic query `CASE`

That all being said there is a way to force a `CASE` behaviour via dynamic query like the one posted by **[Sushil Sharma](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52965136/6059896)**.

There is a **catch however**! Using dynamic query, when it is not required, will give any potential attacher one more attacking vector via [SQL Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/sql-injection?view=sql-server-2017) so in my eyes it is better to use a simple solution `IF` ... `ELSE IF` which executes already predefined procedures.

Answer (score 2):

Tell your lead that he is wrong (in a more polite way, perhaps). There is no CASE *statement* in T-SQL, only a case *expression*. So keep using them IF that you have now.