# How to use if else inside select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have a stored procedure given below and i want to use if else inside select query

```
ALTER PROCEDURE updatepriority
    @sort smallint
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT    
        Request.SubmitTime, Request.CommitTime, 
        (CASE WHEN Priority.Priority = 'Live Demo' THEN 1 WHEN Priority.Priority = 'Priority Re-do' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END) AS Sort1,
END
```

When `@sort = 1` I want to use another case statement and I do not want to include the whole statement with if else

Something like below

```
IF (@sort = 1)
BEGIN
    (CASE WHEN Priority.Priority = 'Live Demo' THEN 1 WHEN Priority.Priority = 'Priority Re-do' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END) AS Sort1,
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    (CASE WHEN Priority.Priority = 'Live Demo' THEN 1 WHEN Priority.Priority = 'Conditional Live' THEN 2 WHEN Priority.Priority = 'Priority Re-do' THEN 3 ELSE 4 END) AS Sort1,
END
```

But the above query throws an error as we cannot use if else inside select statement

Comment: I'd use a similar approach to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52964710/using-case-statement-in-stored-procedure

Answer (score 0):

yes, there's no `else` in `sql server`, but you can have this instead.

```
if(@sort=1)

BEGIN
    SELECT    Request.SubmitTime, Request.CommitTime, 
          (CASE WHEN Priority.Priority = 'Live Demo' THEN 1 WHEN Priority.Priority = 'Priority Re-do' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END) AS Sort1 ....
END

if(@sort!=1)
BEGIN
    SELECT    Request.SubmitTime, Request.CommitTime, 
          (CASE WHEN Priority.Priority = 'Live Demo' THEN 1 
            WHEN Priority.Priority = 'Conditional Live' THEN 2 
            WHEN Priority.Priority = 'Priority Re-do' THEN 3 ELSE 4 END) AS Sort1,
 ....
END
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to not use the select statement in both if/else branches, then the only option is to use dynamic SQL for the CASE assembly, as below:

```
create table #test (
    Priority varchar(30)
);

insert #test (Priority)
values 
    ('Live Demo'), 
    ('Priority Re-do'), 
    ('Conditional Live'), 
    ('ABC');

declare @sort smallint = 1;
declare @sqlStmt varchar(max);

if(@sort=1)
BEGIN
    set @sqlStmt = '
    (CASE 
        WHEN Priority.Priority = ''Live Demo'' THEN 1 
        WHEN Priority.Priority = ''Priority Re-do'' THEN 2 
        ELSE 3 END) AS Sort1';

END
ELSE
BEGIN
    set @sqlStmt = '
    (CASE 
        WHEN Priority.Priority = ''Live Demo'' THEN 1 
        WHEN Priority.Priority = ''Conditional Live'' THEN 2 
        WHEN Priority.Priority = ''Priority Re-do'' THEN 3 
        ELSE 4 END) AS Sort1';
END

set @sqlStmt = 'select Priority.Priority, ''SubmitTime'' as SubmitTime, ' + @sqlStmt + ' from #test as Priority order by Sort1';

exec (@sqlStmt);
```

Of course, you can take only you need from this (the sql dynamic part..).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to nest `CASE` to make a bit of boolean logic

```sql
SELECT    
  Request.SubmitTime,
  Request.CommitTime,
  CASE WHEN @sort = 1 THEN
      CASE WHEN Priority.Priority = 'Live Demo' THEN 1
           WHEN Priority.Priority = 'Priority Re-do' THEN 2
           ELSE 3
      END
  ELSE
      CASE WHEN Priority.Priority = 'Live Demo' THEN 1
           WHEN Priority.Priority = 'Conditional Live' THEN 2
           WHEN Priority.Priority = 'Priority Re-do' THEN 3
           ELSE 4
      END
  END AS Sort1,
....
```

You can even combine the two branches to make it more concise, but the above method is the most straightforward